# What is the format of an EOS wallet address?

Tags: brain-wallet, address

A Bitcoin address is base58 of the hashed public key, you can find a more detailed explanation here https://gobittest.appspot.com/Address

Is there any resource out there explaining in similar fashion how an EOS wallet addresses are generated?

size of address
checksum
characters used
 
etc.

Answer (score 1):

EOS Wallet address is a 12 character long name with the following characters:
`.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345`. a-z (lowercase), 1-5 and . (period)

Its different from bitcoin, as the "wallet address" is actually a human readable name. An account has at least one key, but can have more. Those allow you do set different kind of permissions. The private and public keys that controls the accounts follow the these rules: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc

You can check more details on EOS accounts here: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

EOSIO is using Elliptic curve cryptography to generate wallet keys and for resources you may refer https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc this github repo.

Comment: I found it quite technical, I couldn't find out the size of address, what encoding/characters used, is starting with EOS obligatory .. checksum structure